# how to add/import objective-c files to a swift app

Tags: objective-c, swift, interop, xcode6

just beginning with swift (absolut newby) i want to use existing objective-c files, i.e. vfr by Julius Oklamcak.

In "Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C" stands: 
"To import a set of Objective-C files in the same app target as your Swift code, you rely on an Objective-C bridging header to expose those files to Swift. Xcode offers to create this header file when you add a Swift file to an existing Objective-C app, or an Objective-C file to an existing Swift app."

My silly question: what means "import"?
If i only use "File/Add Files to ...", the dialog "Would you like to configure an Objecive-C bridging header?" will not appear.

When i use "File/New/File/Cacao Class (???)", the dialog appears, but only once?!

Is where any way to import a bundle/set of files? A lot of them in vfr...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google swift bridging header.
See the first result. 
I need 21 more characters.

Comment: Dear Thomas, dont understand... :-(

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html is the first that comes up on Google. Please read that article.

Comment: I can't help. That clearly describes that you have to create a .h file named <proj>-Bridging-Header.h and add the #import to that. Then in the project settings you must name that header file in the according option. Now you can `import obj-c-class` in your Swift source.

Comment: OK, am i right, that i just copy the h.- and m.-files in may swift-project and build the <proj>-Bridging-Header.h manually? Now way to let do this by XCode?

Comment: Yep, That's correct. You must do that manually. Reason is probably easily because Apple want to turn the ship towards Swift and not have one maneuver back.